# A remark on projections in von Neumann algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be  a von Neumann algebra and $e,f$ be projections in $M$. For a given  central projection $z\in M$, is the following true?

$$z(e\vee f)=ze\vee zf$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $M\subset B(H)$.

I think this is pretty straightforward. Looking at the range subspaces, 
$$
z(e\vee f)H=z(\overline{\text{span}}\{eH\cup fH\})=\overline{\text{span}}\{zeH\cup zfH\}=(ze\vee zf)H.
$$